# UITabelView Cell's contents are getting shifted to right in Landscape mode of iphone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x

I am facing this issue while running app on iphone X. I have added all the things label, image view programatically in cell. The app is running fine on all the devices except on iphone X the cell's content views contents are shifted to right.

Please have a look at the below distorted UI.[image]

Not able to see the right hand side label properly. All the help is much appriciated.

Comment: can you share the function in which you are  adding label?

Comment: Thank you Hassan for having a look actually the function is pretty big will be unable to share it. I think it is related to contentInset of Table view cell. @AbuUlHassan

Comment: yes actually for iPhone-X you have to set safe area for leading ,training, top and buttooms

Comment: what can be done for the how can i set constraints to content view or how can i use the contentInset property @AbuUlHassan

Comment: its not medatory to use all constraints but when using anyone or all of above you have to take care of safe-area insets.

Comment: let me give a url for safe area insets.

Comment: https://medium.com/@hassanahmedkhan/playing-it-safe-with-safe-area-layout-guide-b3f09bdc71fe
Please have a look.

Comment: I saw it and i have a doubt here if i bind the safe area giving leading and trailing constraints it will also add the constraints to navigation bar as well and the navigation bar will be cut from both side leading and trailing. @AbuUlHassan

Comment: leading and trailing is not concerned with navigation please give a try if impacts we have the option to revert the changes :D

Comment: still not working @AbuUlHassan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174498/discussion-between-abu-ul-hassan-and-vicky).